# Existence of entire function s.t. for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|\geq 100:|f(z)|=|z|+1$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Is there a function $f$ such that $f$ is entire and for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|\geq 100:|f(z)|=|z|+1$.

An observation is that $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$ and so $f$ must be a polynomial.

Therefore, the problem reduces to showing that no polynomial can uphold the given constraint.

My problem is in doing so. Is there another way?

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$. For a large enough $R>100,|a|$, by Cauchy's formula we get

$$f''(a)=\frac{1}{\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^3}dz\implies $$

$$|f''(a)|\leq\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{|R-a|^3}\cdot2\pi R$$

The latter goes to $0$ as $R\to\infty$, so $f''(a)=0$. Therefore, $f''\equiv 0$.

We get that $f$ is a linear function $f(z)=az+b$.

Comment: Now do the modulus and see what happens. It might be better to work with $|f|^2$ to avoid square roots.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144104/does-there-exists-an-entire-function-such-that-for-each-zc-for-some-constan